# How to check that a macro parameter is an empty list within syntax-case?

Tags: syntax, macros, scheme

How can I test whether a syntax pattern parameter is an empty list? I am testing in guile.

```
(define-syntax mkl
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      [(_ var params code)
       (if (null? (syntax->datum #'params)); doesn't match anyway !!!???
           #'(lambda (var) code)
           #'(lambda (var) (cons 1 code)))])))

;;; try: expecting: (100 200) but got: (1 100 200)
(display
  ((mkl s '() s) '(100 200)))
(newline)
```

However, if I test against a number, it works:

```
(define-syntax mkl2
  (lambda (x)
    (syntax-case x ()
      [(_ var params code)
       (if (= (syntax->datum #'params) 0); matches OK
       #'(lambda (var) code)
       #'(lambda (var) (cons 1 code)))])))

;;; try: expecting: (100 200) and it works OK
(display
 ((mkl2 s 0 s) '(100 200)))
(newline)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there's an extra quotation in there. In the macro, you should perform the check like this:

```
(if (null? (cadr (syntax->datum #'params))) ; access the actual list
```

Or as a workaround, you could call the macro like this:

```
((mkl s () s) '(100 200)) ; quote was removed
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this was an awkward mystery!